# Structured streaming kafka driver relaunch fails with HDFS file rename errors since new name file already exists

Tags: hdfs, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

We are testing restarts and failover with structured streaming in Spark 2.1.

We have a stripped down kafka structured streaming driver that only performs an event count. When we relaunch the driver a second time gracefully (i.e. kill driver with yarn application -kill and resubmit with same checkpoint dir), the driver fails due to aborted jobs that cannot commit the state in HDFS with errors like:

"Failed to rename /user/spark/checkpoints/StructuredStreamingSignalCount/ss_signal_count/state/0/11/temp-1769618528278028159 to /user/spark/checkpoints/StructuredStreamingSignalCount/ss_signal_count/state/0/11/128.delta"

When I look in the HDFS, 128.delta already existed before the error. HDFS fundamentally does not allow rename when the target file name already exists with the rename command. Any insight greatly appreciated!

We are using: 
spark 2.1.0
HDFS/YARN 2.7.3
Kafka 0.10.1

Heji

Answer (score 0):

A bug in spark for not deleting state file before renaming:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19677